# Can I add object in my NSMutableArray from another view (may be it's subview)

Tags: ios, uitableview, object, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray in the ParentViewController that work with UITableView to show object data and have a function to call my created popupView, I want to add new object in my NSMutableArray on this popupView

subview is set in the popupView, it's pass the super view when call popup

like this

```
[self.popViewController showInView:self.navigationController.view
                                   withURL:[self testFilePathURL]
                              withDuration:[NSNumber numberWithInt:CMTimeGetSeconds([soundFileAsset duration])]
                                 withTitle:@"Recorded Audio"
                                  animated:YES];
```

How can I add new object in the subview ?

Comment: u can access the array array data as long as you declared that array as public in your class

Comment: You can access and modify any NSMutableArray for which you have a pointer.  How you get a pointer to it is up to you.  (But note that if you simultaneously modify an array in one thread while accessing it in another you may get a nasty error.)

Answer (score 0):

create an array as public and the import the viewcontroller where this array resides and using an instance of that viewcontroller you can hold on to this array and do necessary steps